# Compiling case class with many parameters causes java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala

I have the following case class with very large number of parameters (150) is causing java.lang.StackOverflowError exception during compilation using sbt (version 0.14):

class definition:

```
case class TestClass(Param1:String,Param2:String,Param3:String,...,Param150:String)
```

Exception during sbt compilation:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\ImportSyncPuffDataApp\target\scala-2.11\classes...
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.bufferErrors(Contexts.scala:332)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.reportErrors(Contexts.scala:333)
...
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

If reduce the number of parameters to 115, it works fine. How can I work around this limit?

Comment: why do you need a case class with 142 parameters? how would you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a larger jvm stack space(default 1M) by add this:

```
-Xss2M
```

On windows platform it should be in `%SBT_HOME%\conf\sbtconfig.txt`

Comment: How do I do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: -Xss2M is a jvm parameter,you can add it to the configurations of the compiler's jvm .

Comment: It helped me a lot. I put -J-Xss4M in my .sbtopts file

Answer (score 0):

Use sbt command line to increase stack size (through JVM parameters):

```
sbt -J-Xss2M -J-Xmx2G
```