# How to fix scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.imports(Contexts.scala:232) in an sbt project?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt

The Issue is with the below Error,

[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] Total time: 11 s, completed Apr 25, 2019 7:11:28 PM

also tried to increase the jmx parameters
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx4048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=4048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled") but it didn't help. All the dependencies seems to resolve properly but this Error is kind of Struck.

```
build.properties
sbt.version=1.2.8
```

```
plugin.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.9")
```

```
And the build.sbt

name := "ProjectNew"

version := "4.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"



fork := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0" % "test",
  ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0.cloudera1").
    exclude("org.mortbay.jetty", "servlet-api").
    exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
    //exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
    exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog").
    //exclude("org.apache.hadooop","hadoop-client").
    exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging") % "provided",
  ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0.cloudera1")
    .exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog","minlog")
    //.exclude("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-client")
     % "provided",
  ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.0.cloudera1")
    .exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog","minlog")
    //.exclude("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-client")
     % "provided",
  "spark.jobserver" % "job-server-api" % "0.4.0",
  "org.scalatest" %%"scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
   "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.6.0"  
 )


//libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
//  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0-cdh5.5.0" % "provided",
//  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.0-cdh5.5.0" % "provided",
//  "org.scalatest"%"scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.4" % "test",
//  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.6.0"  
// )


  resolvers ++= Seq(
    "cloudera" at "http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/",
    "Job Server Bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-jobserver/maven"
)
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

parallelExecution in Test := false

fork in Test := true

javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx4048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=4048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a memory Issue.
I referred to the following Answer: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984767/compiling-case-class-with-many-parameters-causes-java-lang-stackoverflowerror). 
And in my C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig File, I added/increased the below params for memory.

```
-Xmx2G
-XX:MaxPermSize=1000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1000m
-Xss8M
```

And running sbt package has seamlessly worked and Compilation succeeded.
Thank you All.