# How to fix the Error: "org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to run the main class in the scala-sbt project. Running the class is resulting in stackoverflow Error, StackTrace pasted below.

I am sure this is not a code Issue because for the same project I was able to run sbt package by setting the memory in sbt conf file as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55874883.

I tried to set the params in Intellij> Settings> Scala Compile Server, but it didn't help to overcome Error.
JDK: Profile Default
Jvm maximum heap size, MB: 2024
JVM options: -server -Xmx2G -Xss20m -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1000m

IntelliJ:
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Sbt Version: 1.2.8

Scala Version: 2.11.8

```
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
java.lang.StackOverflowError

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.transform(TailCalls.scala:273)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.transform(TailCalls.scala:209)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.noTailTransform(TailCalls.scala:214)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.transform(TailCalls.scala:403)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.transform(TailCalls.scala:209)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.noTailTransform(TailCalls.scala:214)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.transform(TailCalls.scala:403)

    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TailCalls$TailCallElimination.transform(TailCalls.scala:209)

    redacted...
```

Comment: is it still happening in IntelliJ 2019.2?

Comment: Hi Justin, Thank you for following up. I've not Updated by Intellij so far. Will definitely try to reproduce the above once I update.

Answer (score 18):

I've had the same issue with Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.1.1.

None of above options worked for me. But with a hint of the  above answer, I found there was also different setting for the Scala compiler, after changing it the error stopped.

I increased the size of stack trace of the Scala compiler server: `Preferences` -> `Compiler` -> `Scala Compiler` -> `Scala Compiler Server`. Then,  change the JVM options accordingly (In my case, `-server -Xss1024m`).

Comment: Don't forget to restart IntelliJ so that the changes take effect.

Comment: I didn't need to restart IntelliJ. This can save a lot of time when you ar trying a number of settings...

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue with Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4.

In the end, what worked for me was this [solution](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000180999-javac-compiler-fails-with-StackOverflowError?page=1#community_comment_360000045080). Basically, go to `Settings` `->` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `->` `Compiler`

Then, on "User-local build process VM options" set the stack size to a greater value with `-Xss`

In my case, I finally managed to run the tests setting it to `-Xss2048m`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Configure → Edit Custom VM Options and add your changes there

Comment: Mzf but I am unable to find that option anywhere in IntelliJ.

Comment: It is under Help dropdown.

Comment: Added below, but still, have the same problem.
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms128m
-Xmx2G
-Xss8M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1000m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

Comment: Mzf, can this be added elsewhere? Any source on the internet can also help. I did Google and looked up for it, failed to find anything related to this Issue.

Comment: Also requested on IntelliJ Community Forum,
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003554559-Stackoverflow-ERROR-Trying-to-pass-jvm-options-from-Help-Edit-Custom-VM-Options-?page=1#community_comment_360000486919
still not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to do sbt package (so you have sufficient heap size and `-Xss` configured for sbt) but running class still throws java.lang.StackOverflowError try going to

`Settings` `->` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `->` `sbt`

and tick

`sbt shell` `->` `use for:` `project reload` and `builds`

[try those options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFve.png)